# ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package [gem5]

Tags: python, gem5

I am using the configuration Simulation.py in configs/common. I get the error

> ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

The full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/X86/python/m5/main.py", line 438, in main
    exec(filecode, scope)
  File "configs/common/Simulation.py", line 49, in <module>
    from . import CpuConfig
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Simulation.py:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import absolute_import

import sys
from os import getcwd
from os.path import join as joinpath

from . import CpuConfig
from . import BPConfig
from . import MemConfig

import m5
from m5.defines import buildEnv
from m5.objects import *
from m5.util import *

addToPath('../common')
```

I have tried changing to absolute import paths from relative import paths and I still get error. 
This guy had a similar error: https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg16430.html but It didn't fix for me.

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
git SHA: d00aa3658498968f7dc2b586347771734af0d24a
```

Comment: How are you using Simulation.py? Are you calling it from a custom script, or using an in-tree script such as fs.py? What is the full gem5 command line?

Comment: I did build/X86/gem5.opt configs/common/Simulation.py. I now realize this is not how it is supposed to be done. I was experimenting with the configs. Is there a documentation explaining what each config file does or the is only way to this is by going through the files?

Answer (score 0):

After [Eleanor's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56748652/valueerror-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-gem5?noredirect=1#comment100087044_56748652), it seems that they were trying to execute `configs/common/Simulation.py` directly with gem5.opt, which is not supported.

In general, Python scripts under `configs/common` are not meant to be executed directly, and just factor out other scripts.

The most important in-tree scripts that I am aware of are:

- `configs/example/fs.py`: main cross arch full system script
- `configs/example/se.py`: main cross arch syscall emulation script
- `configs/example/arm/fs_bigLITTLE.py`: ARM bigLITTLE system
- `configs/example/arm/starter_fs.py`: ARM minimal system
- `gem5/configs/learning_gem5/`: tutorial scripts for Jason's Learning Gem5 tutorial

So you see that `configs/example/` contains most of the interesting ones. You just have to learn what scripts must contain to be "runnable", the most important component is basically a call to:

```
Simulation.run
```

which actually starts the simulation.

The only considerable documentations I know of are:

1. http://gem5.org/ which is a semi messy wiki, so hit and miss
2. http://learning.gem5.org/ by Jason which shows how to setup some basic Python configs, and is very valuable
3. https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat which contains some setups that just work and can serve as a starting reference